# Isuess with Python turtle library "onclick" function

Tags: python, python-turtle

So, the problem is is that the "onclick" function is not working. It is instead just printing the test code (print('working')) when the code is started. Please help!

```
SubmitButton = turtle.Turtle()
SubmitButton.penup()
SubmitButton.goto(0,-300)
SubmitButton.shape('square')
SubmitButton.shapesize(2)
SubmitButton.fillcolor('red')
SubmitButton.penup()
SubmitButton.goto
SubmitButton.onclick(print("working"))
```

There is the snippet of the code, lemme know if you need anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` needs to be passed a function, which it will call. The function needs to have two arguments. (See the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick), which you should *always* look up before posting here). You're passing it the returned value of a `print()`, which is `None`. You could use a `lambda`, which creates a function that will call `print()` when that function is called:

```
SubmitButton.onclick(lambda x, y: print("working"))
```

Or you could define a function and pass that in:

```
def onclick_function(x, y):
    print("working")

SubmitButton.onclick(onclick_function)
```

Notice though how I'm passing in `onclick_function` but not *calling* that function.

Comment: Do I replace the X, Y with the coords of the button? I tested just calling a function that printed working, and it is still doing the previous thing, printing on start

Comment: X and Y are arguments that are automatically passed to the function that you pass in to `onclick`. They are "the coordinates of the clicked point on the canvas" according to the documentation which I linked. You're free to use them or not.

Comment: It's probably still printing `working` because you're calling the function rather than passing the function itself. There's a huge difference.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I just noticed that and fixed it! Thank you VERY much! Do I give you rep or something? if so how would one do that?

Comment: @CozmoKitten glad that worked. If you feel that my answer was what helped, definitely remember to upvote and accept it.

Comment: how do I accept your answer?